# LiveData doesn't notify UI about changes when used with DataBinding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

I want to change UI as `LiveData` changes when used with DataBinding. But as the `LiveData` is changing it is not reflecting changes in UI.

**MainViewModel.java**

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    /**
     * Boolean variable to see whether user is ClockedIn or ClockedOut
     */
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> isClockedIn;

    public MainViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        isClockedIn = new MutableLiveData<>();
        //...
        calculateClockedInOrNot(PreferencesManager.getString(mContext,PreferencesManager.CLOCK_STATUS_KEY));
    }

    /**
     * An utility function to calculate whether user is clocked in or clocked out,
     * this function is also called within this ViewModel after an api hit
     *
     * if string == "CLOCKED_OUT" or string == "mobileEventType.CLOCK_OUT" => user is clocked out
     * else user is clocked in
     */
    private void calculateClockedInOrNot(String string) {
        if (string.equals("CLOCKED_OUT") || string.equals("mobileEventType.CLOCK_OUT")) {
            //user is clocked out
            isClockedIn.setValue(false);
        } else {
            //user is clocked in
            isClockedIn.setValue(true);
        }
    }
    //getter function
    public MutableLiveData<Boolean> isClockedIn() {
        return isClockedIn;
    }
    //other function left for brevity
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Obtain the ViewModel component.
    mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
    // Inflate view and obtain an instance of the binding class.
    ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    // Assign the component to a property in the binding class.
    binding.setData(mainViewModel);
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="data"
        type="com.app.bidunity.viewmodel.MainViewModel" />
</data>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/img_hight_location"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@{data.clockedIn ? @drawable/ic_location_on : @drawable/ic_location_off}"/>
        <!--Other view left for brevity-->
 </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.bidunity"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}


}

dependencies {
def arch_version = "2.0.0-rc01"

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
//material library
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
// ViewModel and LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$arch_version"

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

I am using *Android studio 3.3 Canary 11* with *gradle 4.10.1* and `onclick` with databinding is working fine within viewmodel, but even after changing `isClockedIn` the `ImageView` is not changing it's drawable. I have tried everything, I even debugged to see if `isClockedIn` is changing or not in middle of the run, and yes it's value is changing

Comment: In my `MainActivity` I forget this `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);`, adding this line and everything worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make your **`isClockedIn`** variable **Observable Field**,

So replace it from

```
public boolean isClockedIn = false;
```

to

```
public ObservableBoolean isClockedIn = new ObservableBoolean();
```

*Note : also make sure that xml has the same variable name as in your **ViewModel***

Refer [**here**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability#observable_fields)

**Edit:**

If you don't want to make **ObservableField**, then it'll take some other changes.

Inspite of **ObservableField**, you'll need to make your observable extend **`BaseObservable`** and in your *livedata* you'll required to call `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.isClockedIn);` after boolean value change.

---

If you want to use LiveData as observer, first is to provide your binding a life cycle

```
// Specify the current activity as the lifecycle owner (in your activity/fragment).
binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);
```

In your ViewModel, take LiveData object to observe change and apply [**Transformation**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations) on it:

```
MutableLiveData<Boolean> dataToBeObserve = new MutableLiveData<>();
LiveData booleanDataChange = Transformations.map(dataToBeObserve, dataToBeObserve-> dataToBeObserve.value);
```

Now, use this **`booleanDataChange`** to xml and change your MutableLiveData value to observe data change event.

*Note: You can use same LiveData for change events, just need to split defination to constructor call.*

Comment: I am using LiveData and MutableLiveData, can I use these instead of ObservableBoolean

Comment: I don't want to use BaseObservable, because I am using architecture component, I want to achieve it with ViewModel and LiveData...... if you can see my MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel which is a class provided by android architecture component

Comment: It's not possible without above solutions when using it with architecture components. Up to my knowledge it's like this is, Let me know if i'm wrong & you found any other way.

Comment: What's the point of having liveData and MutableLiveData if you can't notify xml, and it is mentioned it can be used https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#livedata

Comment: Yes you can do like that also.

Comment: I tries using MutableLiveData<Boolean> and tried isClockedIn = new MutableLiveData<>(); isCLockedIn.postValue(true) but it is not working

Comment: did you put the observe method on `isClockedIn` when you used MutableliveData? @L-X

Comment: No, I used this public MutableLiveData<Boolean> isClockedIn = new MutableLiveData<>(); the reason why I am using MutableLiveData is that they automatically handle what Observable do, they are kind of same thing as what Observable use to do

Comment: @L-X Please try the below answer. And update if it is working. Follow the steps as directed.

Comment: I used ObservbleBoolean and it is working, I will check your answer will notify you

Comment: Just using plain `LiveData` (and no observable) along with setting `binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);` worked, thanks

Comment: I also faced similar issue where binding.setLifecycleOwner(this);saved me